# Image misaligned in buttons in firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, button

I'm trying to convert some divs to buttons. They work fine on ie and chrome but on firefox even though I set the images and divs to the same size the images are still bigger than the divs. The images also don't touch the left border of the div as they should even though they do in the other browsers. I have tried setting a browser specif css rule but it doesn't appear to have any affect. Does any one know how i can solve this? By the way I have only converted the first div to a button at the moment.

The page that I'm having a problem with is hear (the button is near the bottom of the page and is titled "Fears/phobias"):
http://www.swanleyhypnotherapist.co.uk/

Comment: Put the minimum that demonstrated the problem into fiddle. Might end up with some help

Comment: I understand this doesn't answer your question directly, but from a semantics point of view, it would be more appropriate to use the `<a>` tag instead of the `button` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't do that to start with because im sure when I did this before at school it didn't work. Though it appears to do now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use background images? Better yet, CSS sprites? Then it wouldn't matter what kind of element you wanted to use (DIV, BUTTON, A, etc.), as long as you can give the element a `display: inline-block` or `display: block` attribute. Adjusting the position of the background image (x, y) should be trivial. To move the text away from the background image (if there's a visual collision), use `text-indent` to adjust the distance between background image and text. Obviously, if you simply want the entire background to be an image, you needn't worry about `text-indent`.

Comment: In my version of FireFox (19.0) that button - and all buttons - appear to be fine.

Comment: Also in my version of FireFox (19.0) that button - and all buttons - appear to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.graphic {
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    boder: 0
}
```

for a start, you seriously need to post `code`...